# Conditional distribution of the sum of k, independent ordered draws

Tags: probability, convolution, order-statistics

Suppose I make k independent draws from the same distribution (say uniform).
The distribution of the sum of these order statistics should equal the distribution of the sum of k independent random variables, am I right?
But what if I am also told that the highest of these draws has a value less (or equal than) x? In other words, what is the expression for the distribution of the sum of k order statistics conditional on the highest of them not exceeding x?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the highest draw is at most $x$, then you know that all $k$ draws are at most $x$, and otherwise they are arbitrary. So in effect you are sampling from your distribution conditioned on being at most $x$.

For example, if your initial distribution is uniform on $[0,1]$ and $x \in [0,1]$, then the expected sum of $k$ independent draws conditioned on the maximum being at most $x$ is the same as the expected sum of $k$ independent draws of a uniform $[0,x]$ variable, which is $kx/2$.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. However, I need/would like the distribution of the "sum of k independent draws conditioned on the maximum being at most x", not just the expected value.

Comment: I am actually after the pdf if that wasn't clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let me repeat my second sentence: "So in effect you are sampling from your distribution conditioned on being at most $x$". Spend a few hours pondering this, and only if you are still stuck, come back here.

Comment: Ok, will do. thanks

Comment: So I did a bit of pondering, and I came up with the following (but I am not sure it's right). Take for simplicity N=2. If I condition the highest draw not to exceed x, the distribution of the sum of the two draws would equal the distribution of the sum of two draws from a uniform on [0,x]?
But here is the problem. What is this distribution? The distribution of the sum of two draws from a uniform [0,1] is a triangular (0,2) with mean 1, but what about the distribution of the sum of two uniforms on [0,x]? What about other distributions?

Comment: Right, the distribution of the sum of $N$ draws is as you describe it. Since you can obtain a uniform $[0,x]$ random variable by taking a uniform $[0,1]$ random variable and dividing by $x$, I think you actually know the distribution of the sum of two uniform $[0,x]$ random variables. For general distributions, you can always calculate the answer, though there is no reason for it to be nice.

Comment: For the general case, would the density equal the convolution of the n random variables divided by the probability that all of them are less than x? Which, if they are indpendent, should be F(x)^N

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's not so simple.